# Need assistance solving the exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, exponentiation

I need to solve the exponential equation $$\frac{(x + 4)10^x}{x - 3} = 2x(10^x),$$assuming the fact that $2^x$ is always positive.

The example uses the case $x^3-2^x - 3(2^x) = 0$ factors out $2^x$ leaving $2^x (x^3-3) = 0$.  They then apply the zero-product property and solve $2^x$ and $x^3 - 3 = 0$.  Does this still apply for my more complex question?  In that case, would I get one side of the equation to $0$, then apply this same property?  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation by $x-3$, and transpose everything to the left. Factor and note what you have...

Comment: Since $10^x$ is not equal to $0$, you can divide both sides by $10^x$ to get an equivalent equation.  By the way, there is (currently) a typo in the explanatory material that involves $2^x$.

Comment: That was probably my typo, but was just an example of the procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
& \frac{(x+4)10^x-2x(x-3)10^x}{x-3}=0\\
\Rightarrow \quad & \frac{10^x(-2x^2+7x+4)}{x-3}=0\\
\Rightarrow \quad & -2x^2+7x+4=0 \quad \text{and} \quad x\neq 3
\end{align*}